# how to write the CMake file properly when two subdirectories reference the same library?

Tags: cmake

I have a directory structure like this

```
external/
   loglib/

subdir1/
   CMakeList.txt // link with loglib 
subdir2/
   CMakeList.txt // link with loglib , the same loglib.
main.cc
CMakeList.txt // link with subdir1 subdir2 as if they are isolated libs
```

will `loglib` be duplicated as a consequence of this? what's the best practice to do this? should i just combine the functionality under the main CMakefile (which will only link `loglib` once ) and forget about isolation such as addsubdirectory?

Comment: "will loglib be duplicated as a consequence of this?" - The library definitely won't be duplicated just because of **linking**.

Comment: what if they link statically

Comment: Static linking twice with the same library is perfectly correct. That is, the library won't be duplicated.